# Swift5とObjective-Cを相互連携させたい

Tags: swift, objective-c, swift5

ブリッジヘッダーを作成し、swiftからObjectiveCのメソッドが動くことを確認できました。

TestProvider.swift

```
import NetworkExtension
//@objc(TestProvider)
class TestProvider: NEAppPushProvider {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    // MARK: - NEAppPushProvider Life Cycle
    override func start(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
    
    override func stop(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
        NSLog("end")
    }
}
```

ブリッジヘッダー
TestProvider-Bridging-Header.h

```
#ifndef TestProvider_Bridging_Header_h
#define TestProvider_Bridging_Header_h

#import "TestObjC.h"

#endif /* TestProvider_Bridging_Header_h */
```

Objective-Cのヘッダー
TestObjC.h

```
#ifndef TestObjC_h
#define TestObjC_h

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface TestObjC : NSObject
- (void) printTest;

@end

#endif /* TestObjC_h */
```

Objective-Cのソース
TestObjC.mm

```
#include "TestObjC.h"
※（１）

@implementation TestObjC {
    
}

-(void) printTest {
    NSLog(@"printTest");
    
}
@end
```

printTestの文字列が、コンソールログに出力されていることを確認できました。
相互に連携したいため、以下をサイトを参考にしました。

https://qiita.com/edo_m18/items/861d090a5471f4f0eeae

TestProvider.swift

```
import NetworkExtension
@objc(TestProvider)
class TestProvider: NEAppPushProvider {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    // MARK: - NEAppPushProvider Life Cycle
    override func start(completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {
        completionHandler(nil)
    }
    
    override func stop(with reason: NEProviderStopReason, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        completionHandler()
        NSLog("end")
    }

    // ファクトリメソッドを定義しておく
    class func create() -> TestProvider {
        return TestProvider()
    }
    @objc func doMethod() -> () {
        NSLog("start")
    }
}
```

ビルドできたので、次にObjective-C側にコードを追加したのですが、Testが見つからないとエラーとなってしまいました。
　　
TestObjC.mm

```
#include "TestObjC.h"

@implementation TestObjC {

}

-(void) printTest {
    NSLog(@"printTest");
    TestProvider *test = [TestProvider create];※

}
@end
```

※のTestProvider箇所２箇所で以下のエラーが出てしまします。

> Unknown type name 'TestProvider'
> どのように連携させたらいいのか悩んでおります。
> 何かいいアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いいたします。

＃ご指摘いただいた通りコードが不正でしたので修正しました

次に、swiftのヘッダーを追加すればいいのではと、TestObjC.mm側の※（１）に#import "TestProvider-Swift.h"を入れてみたのですが、以下のような注意が出ており、

1. In file included from /Users/ホゲ/Desktop/test/test/TestObjC.mm:10:
   TestProvider-Swift.hを見ると

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC17TestProvider17TestProvider")
@interface Test : NEAppPushProvider ※１
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
- (void)startWithCompletionHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(NSError * _Nullable))completionHandler;
- (void)stopWithReason:(NEProviderStopReason)reason completionHandler:(void (^ _Nonnull)(void))completionHandler; ※２
- (void)doMethod;
@end
```

※１箇所に
「Cannot find interface declaration for 'NEAppPushProvider', superclass of 'TestProvider'」
※２箇所に
「Expected a type]
のエラーが出ておりました。

TestProvider.swiftで継承しているNEAppPushProviderが、swiftとObjectiveCで型が違うため怒られている気もするのですが、どのように連携させたらいいのか悩んでおります。
何かいいアドバイスがあればよろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「ビルドできた」と書かれていますが、あなたが掲載されたコードには全角の空白が含まれていたり、現在のSwift標準ライブラリには存在しない`println`が使われたいたりと、**絶対にビルドできない** ものになっています。ご質問のために手作業でいじられたコードを掲載されたのでしょうか? とにかくそのせいで一体どんな問題点があるのかがわからなくなっていますので、実際に試されたコードを **一文字も編集することなく** そのまま掲載するようにしてください。また「TestObjC.mm側の１０行目に」と言うのは具体的にどこのことでしょうか? 掲載されたコードのちょうど10行目ですと全然別のエラーが出てしまいます。ほとんど重複になっても具体的に`#import "Test-Swift.h"`をどこに入れたのかがわかるようにしてください。

Comment: OOPer様、コードが不正でしたので修正しました。

Answer (score 0):

ご質問内容の修正ありがとうございました。最新のXcode12.5で試したところ、ご記載の内容と発生した事象がほぼ一致(※)しましたので、回答を書かせていただきます。

(※ TestProvider-Swift.h の`@interface`部は、`@interface Test`ではなく、`@interface TestProvider`になるはずです。)

> TestObjC.mm側の※（１）に#import "TestProvider-Swift.h"を入れてみた

Swiftのコードを使うObjective-Cのコードに入れるSwiftヘッダのimportを書く位置はその場所(実装ファイル側の他のimport/includeの後)で構いません。

> ※１箇所に
> 「Cannot find interface declaration for 'NEAppPushProvider', superclass of 'TestProvider'」

通常は、上記の位置にヘッダをimportすればOKなのですが、ご質問のように **Objective-C++** ファイルの場合、ヘッダ内の`@import NetworkExtension;`の部分が有効にならず、記載されたようなエラーになってしまうようです。ご自身で関連するimportを追加してやってください。

#### TestObjC.mm

```
#include "TestObjC.h"
#import <NetworkExtension/NetworkExtension.h> // <-
#import "TestProvider-Swift.h"

//...
```

(特にC++の機能を使用している部分は無いようですが、意図的にObjective-C++としてコンパイルさせたい部分がどこかにあるのでしょうか?)

---

また、Objective-C側から使いたいSwiftのメソッド・プロパティには全て`@objc`を付けてやらないといけません。

#### TestProvider.swift

```
//...
    @objc class func create() -> Test { // <-
        return Test()
    }
//...
```

---

なお、現在のXcodeには若干のバグがあるようで、Swiftヘッダ中の一部にエラーが表示されると、importを追加するなどしてエラーを解消してビルドが成功しても、そのエラー表示が消えないことがあるようです。Build Succeededと表示されれば問題ないので無視してください。
(確実に消す方法はわからなかったのですが、いつのまにか消えていました。)